# looking for a web service to get product information

Tags: web-services, search, web, product

Im looking for a web service that can return information on a product. Much like the barcode scanning apps.

Im hoping to implement barcode scanning (which is another question entirely) which will then return a product ID or description which I can then call a webservice for to get details on the product.

Im not interested in product pricing but the actual description or type of product.

Is there anyone that knows of a web service for this kind of information?

It does not nessesarily have to be a web service, im happy to call a website if I can read information from it.

Any other suggestions would be helpful also

Comment: what kind of product? is it yours?

Comment: @emaillenin - its could be anything really, food products, electrical. Anything that comes in packaging. mostly food products though, they would be most important

Comment: I dont think you can find such a **generic** web service in the web

Comment: I think you have answered my question in another post (http://www.webservicelist.com/api/web_services_business_finance_yahoo_shopping_web_services_product_searchapi_websitedesign239639.html) - Ill see if there are any other responses and then mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is looking like a good place to start (thanks to emaillenin)

http://www.webservicelist.com/webservices/c.asp?cid=30&web+services

Answer (score 0):

I'm representative of http://aerse.com. You could have a look at Aerse. It provides:

- product specifications (CPU, display diagonal, RAM & etc)
- product images (raw full-scale and thumbnails)
- its free
- no limit on requests